# setText() after inflating

Tags: android

I'm using a ViewPager in my project, and having a little problem at setting different data on the same layout. So I need to use a setText on my textViews to customize each page.
But I can't setText() in TextView after inflating ViewGroup that includes that TextView.
Here's the code:

```
public class ScheduleActivity extends Activity {

    private List<View> mPages;
    private ViewPager mPager;
    private TitlePageIndicator mTitleIndicator;
    private ArrayList<String> titles;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.pages);
        initUi();
    }

    private void initUi() {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        mPages = new ArrayList<View>();
        titles = new ArrayList<String>();

        titles.add(getString(R.string.monday));
        titles.add(getString(R.string.tuesday));
        titles.add(getString(R.string.wednesday));
        titles.add(getString(R.string.thursday));
        titles.add(getString(R.string.friday));
        titles.add(getString(R.string.saturday));

        for (String title : titles) {

            TextView[] text = new TextView[7];
            text[0] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
            text[1] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text2);
            text[2] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text3);
            text[3] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text4);
            text[4] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text5);
            text[5] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text6);
            text[6] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text7);

            for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
                text[i].setText(R.string.monday);
            }

            View day = inflater.inflate(R.layout.schedule, null);

            day.setTag(title);
            mPages.add(day);
        }

        MainPageAdapter adapter = new MainPageAdapter(mPages);
        mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        mPager.setCurrentItem(0);

        mTitleIndicator = (TitlePageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.indicator);
        mTitleIndicator.setViewPager(mPager);
        mTitleIndicator.setCurrentItem(0);
        final float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        mTitleIndicator.setTextSize(15 * density); // 15dp
        mTitleIndicator.setFooterLineHeight(1 * density); // 1dp
        mTitleIndicator.setFooterIndicatorHeight(3 * density); // 3dp
        mTitleIndicator.setFooterIndicatorStyle(IndicatorStyle.Underline);
        mTitleIndicator.setFooterColor(0x34B4E3);
        mTitleIndicator.setTextColor(0xAA000000);
        mTitleIndicator.setSelectedColor(0xFF000000);
        mTitleIndicator.setSelectedBold(true);
    }
}
```

Everything works just great if I remove the `setText()` line. Here's the LogCat:

```
02-15 18:17:54.294: D/AndroidRuntime(465): Shutting down VM
02-15 18:17:54.323: W/dalvikvm(465): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
02-15 18:17:54.353: E/AndroidRuntime(465): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-15 18:17:54.353: E/AndroidRuntime(465): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.stiggpwnz.schedule/com.android.stiggpwnz.schedule.ScheduleActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-15 18:17:54.353: E/AndroidRuntime(465):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
02-15 18:17:54.353: E/AndroidRuntime(465):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
02-15 18:17:54.353: E/AndroidRuntime(465):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
02-15 18:17:54.353: E/AndroidRuntime(465):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
02-15 18:17:54.353: E/AndroidRuntime(465):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-15 18:17:54.353: E/AndroidRuntime(465):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-15 18:17:54.353: E/AndroidRuntime(465):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
02-15 18:17:54.353: E/AndroidRuntime(465):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-15 18:17:54.353: E/AndroidRuntime(465):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-15 18:17:54.353: E/AndroidRuntime(465):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
02-15 18:17:54.353: E/AndroidRuntime(465):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
02-15 18:17:54.353: E/AndroidRuntime(465):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-15 18:17:54.353: E/AndroidRuntime(465): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-15 18:17:54.353: E/AndroidRuntime(465):  at com.android.stiggpwnz.schedule.ScheduleActivity.initUi(ScheduleActivity.java:63)
02-15 18:17:54.353: E/AndroidRuntime(465):  at com.android.stiggpwnz.schedule.ScheduleActivity.onCreate(ScheduleActivity.java:36)
02-15 18:17:54.353: E/AndroidRuntime(465):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
02-15 18:17:54.353: E/AndroidRuntime(465):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
02-15 18:17:54.353: E/AndroidRuntime(465):  ... 11 more
```

Line 63 is setText() line.

UPD: changed it to look like this, but still the same exception:

```
    day = inflater.inflate(R.layout.schedule, null);
    day.findViewById(R.layout.schedule);

    for (String title : titles) {

        TextView[] text = new TextView[7];
        text[0] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
        text[1] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text2);
        text[2] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text3);
        text[3] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text4);
        text[4] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text5);
        text[5] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text6);
        text[6] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text7);

        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            text[i].setText(R.string.monday);
        }

        day.setTag(title);
        mPages.add(day);
    }
```

UPD 2: this is how it started to work:

```
View day = inflater.inflate(R.layout.schedule, null); TextView tv = (TextView)day.findViewById(R.id.text1);
```

Comment: can you also show you layout file where you have these textviews.

Comment: Question why do you create TextView[] text = new TextView[7]; and inflations in a loop? i don't see the sense in the second loop within a loop either....

Comment: b'cos I'll need that loop later. I just got where the problem is. I haven't those textViews in my main layout (R.layout.pages), but I have them in my other layout, that i'm inflating (R.layout.schedule). So what I need right now is how to refer to the TextViews that are not in my layout, but in the layout that i'm inflating.

Comment: can you post your `R.layout.pages` xml?

Comment: @NizamutdinovAdel try  `View day = inflater.inflate(R.layout.schedule, null); TextView tv = (TextView)day.findViewById(R.id.text1);`

Comment: the problem isnt in my xml's, the problem is in the way how im inflating stuff, i cant really get how to do it properly

Comment: @Sergey Benner thanks a bunch, it worked! now I know how to inflate stuff properly! yay!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is here:

```
private void initUi() {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
```

You haven't yet inflated the layout, and therefore when you write

```
text[0] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
```

findview will return null, because there are no views to search for!

you must first inflate the layout and only AFTER you can programmatically change its content.

Comment: i didn't get it, what shoul I do?

Answer (score 1):

If you get a NullPointerException on a call to TextView setText, then you need to check your layout file to make sure you have the right ID's on your TextViews.  findViewById is returning a null ref which means the ID you're passing doesn't exist in the layout being used (R.layout.pages)

Comment: Right, I have those id's in R.layout.schedule, which i'm inflating into the R.layout.pages. How can I refer to a R.layout.schedule's TextViews?

Comment: You're inflating layout.schedule AFTER trying to resolve your TextViews from it.  You need to inflate "day" before your loop, and then call day.findViewById.  The way you're doing it now, you're finding views by id on the main layout of the Activity, which is layout.pages.

Comment: just updated the question, posted the code, but it still isnt working. can't really get what to do.